# Hbase Indexer for Solr alternatives?

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase

HBase Indexer from HDPSearch helps push all updates in HBase to Solr. With recent release of HDPSearch 4.0 does not seem to support HBase Indexer anymore. We have huge data in HBase that needs to be indexed. We are mainly looking for a way to index data in HBase near real time. If not HDPSearch, what are the other options to index data in HBase 2.0?

Comment: Cloudera has Lily indexer for HBase as well. In CDH6.1 it supports HBase 2.0+ with indexing to Solr 7.4. Disclaimer: I work at Cloudera.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Our workflows are currently on HDP platform. Do you think we could use the Lily HBase Indexer on HDP HBase 2.0?